# How are gzip content stored in a file?

Tags: c++, file, compression, gzip, zlib

I am able to compress certain content with "gzip" format and store it in a file. This content can be decompressed programatically within my code.
But I can't "gunzip" them using command line or other tools. e.g. "Hello World" (11 bytes) is compressed properly as 'test.txt.gz', but upon double clicking or from command line, it gives below error:

[image]

On the other hand, if I store the same content in the .txt file and gzip that .txt, then it's decompressed properly.

What is the correct way to store gzip content into a file?

---

Here is the [C++14 source code](https://ideone.com/SFTrvj) used for compression/decompression (Referred from: [Compress string with GZip using qCompress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734831/compress-string-with-gzip-using-qcompress)).
[Hex dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614850/514235) (`xxd -p /home/milind/Desktopp/test.txt.gz`):

> 1f8b080000000000000b789cf348cdc9c95728cf2fca49010018ab043d52
> 9ed68b0b000000

Comment: You need to show your code for how you are compressing and storing. Also provide a hex dump of the resulting file that cannot be extracted. Edit your question with this information. Do not provide it in comments.

Comment: @MarkAdler, I have added code & hexdump in the post. Please let me know if it's correct or anything else is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote a gzip header, and then followed that with a zlib-format stream! You need to follow the gzip header with raw deflate data, with no zlib-format wrapper.

Don't use `compress2()`, which can only make a zlib stream. Use the `deflate` functions, documented in zlib.h. You can request that deflate produce a gzip stream, so you don't need to write the header yourself, and you don't need to do your own CRC-32 calculation. That is all provided by zlib.

Comment: For "gzip" creation we have to set `windowBits` as `15 | 16`. What should be the value for "zip" creation? As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506713/how-to-make-a-zip-file-using-zlib) is it not directly supported?

Comment: zlib does not support the zip format directly. You would use raw deflate and raw inflate, and write your own code to processs zip headers and trailers around that and the central directory.